# Is it possible to upgrade from centos 6 kernel 2.6.32-754.25.1.el6.x86_64 to 5.12.1 version?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

You are currently using centos6 kernel 2.6.32-754.25.1.el6.x86_64. I'd like to upgrade to 5.12.1 to take action against the vulnerability in this version, and I'm asking if it's possible.
If it is impossible, I would like to know if there is a way to deal with the vulnerabilities that have occurred.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. There has been major updates in the kernel, and older libc versions do not work properly with this kernel.

CentOS6 has stopped receiving maintenance updates on November 30th 2020, so the only responsible action is to update the complete system.